# Google Sheets ImportXML can parse the results from one <small> but not another

Tags: xpath, xhtml

I'm trying to scrape a list of Yelp results for the restaurant name, the address, and the distance from a given address. I'm able to grab the restaurant name and the address, but I can't seem to get the distance.

[image]

I want to grab the `0.1 km` text, which is in a `<ul>` block like this:

```
<ul class="search-result_tags">
    <li class="tag-18x18_marker-error">
        <small>
            <span aria-hidden="true" style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" class="icon icon--18-marker icon--size-18 icon--error">
                <svg class="icon_svg">
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#18x18_marker"></use>
                </svg>
            </span>

                    0.2 km
        </small>

    </li>
    <li class="tag-18x18_checkmark-neutral-gray">
        <small>
            <span aria-hidden="true" style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" class="icon icon--18-checkmark icon--size-18 icon--neutral-gray">
                <svg class="icon_svg">
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#18x18_checkmark"></use>
                </svg>
            </span>

                    Good for Lunch
        </small>

    </li>
</ul>
```

I used:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.yelp.ca/search?find_desc=lunch&find_loc=1+Hacker+Way,+Menlo+Park,+CA,+United+States&start=0&rpp=40&attrs=GoodForMeal.lunch,RestaurantsPriceRange2.1,RestaurantsPriceRange2.2", "//li[@class='tag-18x18_marker-error']//small")
```

I got #N/A as a result.
But when I changed the `@class` value to grab the `Good for Lunch` text instead, that showed up perfectly fine in Google Sheets.

What am I missing? As far as I can tell the two text values are displayed in the same way, but I can't figure out why one works and the other doesn't. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe ImportXML gets confused by the fact that the page is HTML,not XHTML?

Comment: I am surprised how did you get `Good for Lunch` either ?

Comment: @svasa Hence my confusion... it's my first go at using ImportXML so I have no idea what's normal and what's not, but it seemed to me that if I could get `Good for Lunch` getting the distance should just be a matter of changing the `@class` value